# exempt employee being demanded to start work a X time - is that legal?

Tags: human-resources

I'm an exempt employee who works on average 60-70hours/week and my boss is having kittens over whether I'm spot on time.  Now, I ask you, with all the OT I've worked, coupled with the fact that I'm Exempt - does he have a right?

Comment: Is there anything listed in the Employee Handbook about expected employee hours?

Comment: Under the circumstances, you should be looking for other employment, NOW, not because of the "on-time arrival" chicken excrement but because of the ongoing excessive overtime.  The fundamental unwritten contract of employment in the US for full-time exempt employees is for 40 hours per week.  he 40-hour-workweek became standard in the US because the Early Adopters saw their scrap, rework, and accident rates go through the floor, which sent their profit margins through the ceiling.

Comment: If you are asking about legal rights, you'd have to tell us where you are. If you are asking about moral rights, we can't answer that for you. If you are asking whether he has the practical ability to demand this, see legal, but In the US your only alternatives are to cooperate, to buy (preferably after getting another Jun lined up) out to be fired --  unless can convince the boss that it is in his interest and the that of the company to relax this true.

Comment: Exempt from what?

Comment: Being on time and working overtime are two different things. In general, working overtime doesn't make it OK to be late. However, as pointed out, working 20-30 extra hours per week is just not good.

Comment: @Brandin: The idea is that an hourly employee (in the USA) is there when he or she is told to be there, and gets paid for the hours worked. While an exempt employee gets paid to get the job done. If the boss insists on an employee being there "on time" then that points to being non exempt. There are jobs where people sometimes stay very, very late because of an emergency. Being told off for being late next morning when someone worked past midnight is a sure way to either lose an employee, or to having an employee that will not do overtime anymore.

Comment: @colmde: In the USA, people are either paid by the hour, including overtime, or they are "exempt" which means they are not being paid for overtime. The poster says "60 to 70 hours work a week". I had jobs where overtime was paid plus 50 percent, so 60 to 70 hours work would be 70 to 85 hours paid. The poster being exempt means she is getting paid for 40 hours.

Comment: Does the boss actually know you're working 60-70 hours a week? If s/he is so pernickety about sticking to the exact working hours, that means you should be going home on time as well as arriving on time. If these extra hours were more than a week or two, it's clear the boss needs to hire an additional employee. In answer to your question, he has the right to get you to come in on time, but not to make you work those extra hours.

Comment: @gnasher729 I think you're right about this case (20-30 hours overtime), but for the general case (say, 15 minutes) I don't see how overtime makes it automatically OK to be late in kind (e.g. if you need to be there at a certain time to please your boss). Point is, you need to discuss it with the boss (hey, I was late last night, so I'm going to leave early today).

Comment: There are many exempt jobs where you have to be on time to start and may end of putting in lots of extra hours.  Help desk for example.  Support hours start at 8am and you have to be ready to pickup the phone at 8am.  There are days that a critical calls comes in 5 minutes before support hours are over and you need to stay late to fix it.

Comment: 60-70 hour weeks are ridiculously unsustainable. If you're in a logic-thinking based profession, after 40 hours, your productivity will be close to zero or negative.

Answer (score 8):

If your boss is so worried that you arrive at work in time, there's a simple way to achieve that: Tell you to go home after eight hours work.

60 to 70 hours a week *will* destroy your health. You need to do something about it. Being exempt doesn't mean you are the bosses slave. If it takes 60 to 70 hours to do the job, then he needs to hire someone else.

I'd recommend searching for a new job, while reducing your working hours. You reduce your working hours by leaving after eight hours, or by being sick after a long day. Can your boss afford to live without your work? If the answer is no, you are safe. If the answer is yes, why are you working 60 to 70 hours?